# Run 3 php commands from SH script

Tags: php, shell, cron

I am trying to run the following commands from a .sh script at the command line.  The problem is that when I try to run them one after another they give the following error:
"not found.batch_control_files/Res" and "not found.batch_control_files/Condo
" ...if I remove all but one of the commands it runs fine?  I was hoping I could have each command run and then execute the next command...not sure what it is doing here?

```
/usr/bin/php -f run_interactive_job.php batch_control_files/Res
/usr/bin/php -f run_interactive_job.php batch_control_files/Condo
/usr/bin/php -f run_interactive_job.php batch_control_files/Land
```

Comment: What is your part of codes to read the parameters ?

Comment: Can you give a try by providing execution delay between each command.

Comment: I'm really not sure but is it possible that run_interactive_job.php changes the active directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's in "run_interactive_job.php"?

If you use absolute paths you can at least be sure it's looking where you expect.

Comment: Maybe it's possible on Windows, but on Linux/Mac a PHP script changing the current working directory, does not alter the state of the parent process.

Comment: @Evert whoops, yes that's not likely to be the cause, something else at play